# Replace a specific integer value with a string?

Tags: views

I have a View that displays a list of all the content types, with price as one of the fields you can sort and filter by.

However, the client wants to have some items show up without a price, i.e something like "Price on demand" / negotiate.

Therefore I want to replace '0' value to show up as that text (translated for other languages), how would I best do this?

I use some exposed range filter in my view but couldn't see any extra functions to replace values of field items with strings etc.

I would need it changed in the View as well as the items' individual page (and generated PDF file, but that part I can do)

*EDIT:*
I have Better Exposed Filters, but after setting the replacement as:

```
0|Price on demand
```

It didn't seem to work or do anything. However my views uses a template, and I output the price by doing:

```
print render($content['field_price']);
```

So I would first need to check if $content['field_price'] value is 0, then output my text string? Ideally I would prefer using some settings that can handle replacing the value for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like the simplest method:

```
print $content['field_price'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == 0 ? 'Price on demand' : render($content['field_price']);
```

Comment: $content['field_price'] is Array

Comment: So it is. Not 100% sure of the structure of your field_price but something like my updated answer should do the trick...

Comment: Got it working with: $node->field_price['und'][0]['value'] == 0 ? t('Price on demand') : render($content['field_price']);
Thanks